# Dhtmlx scheduler timeline view: Window zoom level breaking the alignment

Tags: html, css, dhtmlx

Hello am using dhtmlx scheduler TimelineView and this lib is working perfectly fine only in 100% zoom level, When user start zooming In/Out the alignment of Scheduler is totally breaking and it creating undesired user experience. Any help could be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no known solution. Various misalignment are possible on non-default zoom levels. 
FYI I work for DHTMLX.